# Does the category of $\text{List}$-algebras have an initial algebra?

Tags: category-theory

In books that tie programming with Category Theory, one can derive a $\text{List}$ as fixed point for a functor

```
ListF a x = NilF | ConsF a x
```

The objective is usually to formalize what it means to define an inductive type such as

```
List a = Nil | Cons a List a
```

which is how we code lists, i.e. it is something like `Cons 1 (Cons 2 Nil) == [1,2]`.
The way I've seen this formalized is by considering fixing a type `a` and considering the functor `ListF a`. Thus, assuming we are in the category of $\text{List}$- algebras, we obtain the initial algebra, which will correspond to our type `List`.
(from what I understood, this is the gist of it).

The thing is, we can also think of `List` as functor that takes types `a` to `List a` and with the usual `List f` as applying `f` to each element in the list.

My question is if in the category of $\text{List}$-algebras we have such initial algebra, and what it would look like.

Comment: In this case you sort of "know what you're aiming for": you want a type with the inductive definition `data MysteryType = MysteryConstructor (List MysteryType)`. Can you think of a way to describe this type? What do objects of this type look like?